# How to get a list of all the USB removable storages attatched in the system using C?

Tags: c, usb-flash-drive

I am writing a program that will copy some files in a USB removable storage. So I need a list of all removable storages available. I am using C. Portablity is preferred.

Comment: It's quite unlikely to find a portable solution to this, since each OS implements it differently.

Comment: This is a platform-specific issue and you haven't told us what your platform is.

Comment: For now, windows will work. But please give me a solution for linux if you can. Windows is high priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possibly libusbx](http://libusbx.org/)

> libusbx is a library that provides generic access to USB devices. As a
>   library, it is meant to be used by developers, to facilitate the
>   development of applications that communicate with USB hardware.
>
> It is portable: Using a single cross-platform API, it provides access
>   to USB devices on Linux, OS X, Windows and OpenBSD.
>
> It is user-mode: No special privilege or elevation is required for the
>   application to communicate with a device.
>
> It is version-agnostic: All versions of the USB protocol, from 1.0 to
>   3.0 (latest), are supported.

See [libusb_get_device_list](http://libusbx.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#gac0fe4b65914c5ed036e6cbec61cb0b97)

```
libusb_context * usb_ctx = NULL;

int main()
{
...
libusb_init(&usb_ctx);
...
libusb_exit(usb_ctx);
...
} 

some_func()
{
...
libusb_device **list;
ssize_t number_of_devices = libusb_get_device_list(usb_ctx, &list);
...
}
```

(warning I found just this online, I have no personal experience with it, code hasn't been tested,
It looks like you need to call libusb_init/libusb_exit before after use see

*http://libusbx.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__lib.html*

and

*http://libusbx.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/contexts.html.h*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I think it is a bit difficult for me, as I am still in the end of the beginner stage. I assume I am dealing with a problem of my higher stage. But anyways, thanks for your help @Roman